# Problemas para exibir um array de funcionarios em uma classe Main

Tags: java

Tenho 3 classes envolvidas neste erro: TestaEmpresa, Empresa,Funcionario.

Minha ideia é criar um array de funcionarios dentro de Empresa e imprimir na TestaEmpresa. Para isso fiz dentro de Funcionario um método chamado "mostra()". Este deveria emitir a saída por meio de um "System.out.prinln()" para cada atributo que estiver em Funcionario. Mas obtive o seguinte erro ao tentar compilar as classes.

> Erro: The method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void).

Vou colocar agora as classes para eventual análise:

TestaEmpresa:

```
package projetoMeuBanco;

public class TestaEmpresa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


//Crie um objeto de classe empresa.

        Empresa empresa = new Empresa();

//Array de Funcionarios:

        empresa.setFuncionarios(new Funcionario[5]);

//Crie alguns funcionarios e preencha seus atributos, em seguida add a classe empresa.

        Funcionario func1 = new Funcionario();
        Funcionario func2 = new Funcionario();
        Funcionario func3 = new Funcionario();
        func1.setNome("Aldo");
        func2.setNome("Baldo");
        func3.setNome("Caldo");

        func1.dataDeNascimento.setDia("16");
        func1.dataDeNascimento.setMes("02");
        func1.dataDeNascimento.setAno("1997");

        func2.dataDeNascimento.setDia("17");
        func2.dataDeNascimento.setMes("03");
        func2.dataDeNascimento.setAno("1998");

        func3.dataDeNascimento.setDia("18");
        func3.dataDeNascimento.setMes("04");
        func3.dataDeNascimento.setAno("1999");


//Add os funcionarios a empresa.

        empresa.adciona(func1);
        empresa.adciona(func2);
        empresa.adciona(func3);




//Usando o foreach percorra funcionarios da empresa.

        for (Funcionario f: empresa.funcionarios)
        {
            System.out.println(f.mostra());
        }
    }
}
```

Empresa:

```
package projetoMeuBanco;

public class Empresa{

 private String nome, cnpj;

 protected Funcionario[] funcionarios;

 private int posicaoLivre;

public void adciona (Funcionario func) {

    this.funcionarios[this.posicaoLivre]=func;

    this.posicaoLivre++;

}

public Funcionario[] getFuncionarios() {

    return funcionarios;

}

public void setFuncionarios(Funcionario[] funcionarios) {

    this.funcionarios = funcionarios;

}


}
```

Funcionario:

```
package projetoMeuBanco;

//Atributos

public class Funcionario {

private String nome;//get e set

private String departamento;//get e set

private double salario=1000;//get

private boolean ativo;//is e set

protected Data dataDeNascimento = new Data();



public void aumentarSalario(double aumento) {

    this.salario=this.salario*aumento;

}

public void mostra() {

    System.out.println("Nome: "+this.nome+".");

    System.out.println("Salário: "+this.salario+".");

    System.out.println("Data de nascimento: "+dataDeNascimento.data());

    System.out.println("Está na empresa?");

    if(ativo) {

        System.out.print("Sim\n");

    }else {

        System.out.print("Não\n");

    }

}
public boolean demite() {

    ativo=false;

    return ativo;

}
public String getNome() {

    return nome;

}

public void setNome(String nome) {

    this.nome = nome;

}

public String getDepartamento() {

    return departamento;

}

public void setDepartamento(String departamento) {

    this.departamento = departamento;

}

public boolean isAtivo() {

    return ativo;

}

public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {

    this.ativo = ativo;

}

public double getSalario() {

    return salario;

}

}
```

Estes códigos estão no mesmo pacote e eu queria chamar o vetor funcionarios que se localiza na classe empresa. Assim usar o método mostra que consta em funcionarios. Mas acredito que esteja tendo algum problema nessa chamada.

Eu não usei nenhum método boolean pelo caminho e ainda assim apareceu este erro falando sobre boleano. Gostaria que me ajudassem a entender melhor porque tive este problema. E o que pode estar causando este erro.

Comment: Observe o seu `if(ativo){...}`, na classe `Funcionario`. Não fica claro se você está usando o ativo do método booleano `demite()` ou se é do método boolenado `isAtivo()`. Olhando seu código, entendi que você deveria/poderia usar `if(isAtivo()){...}`. Se o ativo for verdadeiro, ele imprime sim, senão não;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja a mensagem de erro:

> Erro: The method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void).

Isso significa que na linha que você está imprimindo, está sendo chamado um método `void`, ou seja, um método que não possui retorno:

```
// Classe TestaEmpresa
for (Funcionario f: empresa.funcionarios)
{
    System.out.println(f.mostra());
}

// Classe funcionário, que possui o método mostra
public void mostra() {

    System.out.println("Nome: "+this.nome+".");

    System.out.println("Salário: "+this.salario+".");

    System.out.println("Data de nascimento: "+dataDeNascimento.data());

    System.out.println("Está na empresa?");

    if(ativo) {

        System.out.print("Sim\n");

    }else {

        System.out.print("Não\n");

    }

}
```

O seu método `mostra()` não está retornando o que deve ser imprimido, ele mesmo está imprimindo. Então, para corrigir o problema, é necessário apenas invocar esse método de impressão, sem tentar imprimir o seu retorno vazio:

```
// Classe TestaEmpresa
for (Funcionario f: empresa.funcionarios)
{
    f.mostra();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando executar um `println` em um método que não retorna nada (`void`) segue abaixo o trecho:

```
//Usando o foreach percorra funcionarios da empresa.
for (Funcionario f: empresa.funcionarios)
{
     System.out.println(f.mostra());
}
```

> Tente assim:

```
//Usando o foreach percorra funcionarios da empresa.
for (Funcionario f: empresa.funcionarios)
{
     f.mostra();
}
```